# Meaning of different indicators when using 'ls -F'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm currently studying Bash shell and have encountered command `ls -F`. I know it ls function is to append indicators to items lists, so to distinguish between different file types. I know that `/` is appended to directory and `*` is appended to executable files. But I have checked the manual page on ls command but couldn't find any information on indicator =>@|.

Could someone tell me what they represent? And it would be even better if can inform me where to find this kind of information when in need.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `info ls`, under "What information is listed":

```
‘-F’
‘--classify’
‘--indicator-style=classify’
Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
     Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘*’.  The file
     type indicators are ‘/’ for directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links,
     ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets, ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for
     regular files.  Do not follow symbolic links listed on the command
     line unless the ‘--dereference-command-line’ (‘-H’),
     ‘--dereference’ (‘-L’), or
     ‘--dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir’ options are specified.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Exactly what I needed. Will accept answer as soon as allowed. Btw. I was just wondering if there are other ways to find out the same information. I guess it doesn't hurt to know multiple ways to get things done

Comment: The `info` pages are more detailed than the `man` pages are.  Other than that, there are a lot of books out there.  A good desk-top reference is "Linux in a Nutshell": http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596154493.do

Comment: non-GNU man pages are better than GNU man pages *and* info, for any purpose other than looking up GNU-specific options. Use https://man.freebsd.org/ to see what's in the man pages of other systems.